# calculate transmission delay of network

Tags: networking, delay, router, packets, transmission

I have N packets of size L Mbits and I want to send them from A to B, in between there are two routers and each link has different transmission rate(e.g A to router1 link is 3Mbps, router1 to router2 5Mbps and router2 to B 8Mbps), so How to calculate transmission delay?

Answer (score 0):

R -> rate of transfer of each link in Mbps

For every link Li:
transmission delay of 1st packet=L0/R+L1/R....+Ln/R

in a loop consider,

For every N packet the transmission delay will be (N-1)Li/R+Li/R
and calculate the remaining part

here for you example trans_delay of 1st packet= (M/3+M/5+M/8)
and the rest u can apply the formula above

Comment: for 2nd packet trans_delay won't be same as packets are transferred in store-and-forward manner when your first packet leaves router1 towards router2 the second packet starts its journey from A to router1 in the same time span. for first packet your formula is right, but what about others?